# Amazon S3 - hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

`Amazon S3`, using `rails` and `fog`.
Trying to precompile my assets with `rake assets:precompile`:

message:

```
[WARNING] fog: followed redirect to myproject.de.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com, connecting to the matching region will be more performant
rake aborted!
hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

So there is something with OpenSSL

What I tried already:

1. I have already tried to config certificates in `application.rb` like this: with no success.

   AWS.config(:http_handler => AWS::Http::HTTPartyHandler.new(:ssl_ca_path =>   "/etc/ssl/certs"))
2. also installed `openssl` on Ubuntu 12.04 from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/openssl)

**Question is:**
How Amazon S3 deals with certificates

Comment: Does is work without SSL? Are you using jruby?

Answer (score 26):

Actually you can use a bucket name with a dot. All you have to do is add `:path_style => true` to your `config.fog_credentials`.

In your example, it would give:

```
config.fog_credentials = {
   :provider              => 'AWS',
   :aws_access_key_id     => ENV['S3_KEY'],
   :aws_secret_access_key => ENV['S3_SECRET'],
   :region                => ENV['S3_REGION'],
   :path_style            => true
}

config.fog_directory    = "myproject.de"
```

Comment: or add `Fog.credentials = { path_style: true }` in asset sync initializer

Comment: `:region` _ALSO_ needs to be set, as shown in your example.  If no region is specified, AWS may issue a 301 redirect back to the invalid bucket-name style address, with dots (rather than the path-style address).

Answer (score 17):

## TLDR; Solution

In order to access your S3 bucket URLs via http**S**, you will need to either:

- Choose a bucket name such that it contains no periods '`.`' and use the "[Virtual Hosted–Style](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)" URL, such as 
  `https://simplebucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/myObjectKey` 
  **OR**
- Use the "[Path Style](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#d0e3631)" URL form that specifies the bucket name separately, after the host name, for example: 
  `https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket.mydomain.com/myObjectKey`

With `fog`, you can set the option: `:path_style            => true` as [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20954167/645491) explained.

## The Problem & Explanation

The SSL Certificate Validation problem arises from using dots '`.`' in the S3 Bucket Name along with the "Virtual Hosted–Style Method" URL format.

The [Amazon S3 Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) states that it allows two main URL formats for accessing S3 Buckets and Objects:

1. [Path Style Method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#d0e3631) (being [deprecated](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/))
2. [Virtual Hosted–Style Method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#d0e3665)

So what's happening is this:

1. Fog is trying to request a URL to your bucket like: `https://myproject.de.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/foo/bar`
2. The Hostname in the request is `myproject.de.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
3. SSL Cert for `*.amazonaws.net` is served during SSL TLS Negotiation
4. Fog tries to validate the SSL Cert & CA Cert Chain
5. Fog tries to match the Cert's CN `*.s3.amazonaws.com` against `myproject.de.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`
6. According to [Certificate CN wildcard matching rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743652/645491) in [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1), the sub-subdomain does not match wildcard CN: `*.s3.amazonaws.com`
7. Connection fails with `hostname does not match the server certificate` due to Invalid SSL Cert CA Validation

The dots in S3 URL problem is mentioned [around the internet](https://www.google.com/search?q=SSL%3A+certificate+subject+name+%27*.s3.amazonaws.com%27+does+not+match+target+host+name&oq=SSL%3A+certificate+subject+name+%27*.s3.amazonaws.com%27+does+not+match+target+host+name) such as in the [Drupal Project](https://www.drupal.org/node/1673888), [AWS Forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=69108), [Python Boto Library](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2836) and is very well explained in this blog post entitled: [Amazon S3 Gotcha: Using Virtual Host URLs with HTTPS](https://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/18/amazon-s3-gotcha-using-virtual-host/)  <-- **I highly recommend reading this one for further clarification.**

Answer (score -4):

Problem is with `naming` of `bucket`, in this case : `myproject.de`, which is format that Amazon S3 services do not consider as valid.(no dot in the name).

I have changed the name of bucket from `myproject.de` into `myprojectde` and it works now.

**Rules for Bucket Naming**

> In all regions except for the US Standard region a bucket name must
>   comply with the following rules. These result in a DNS compliant
>   bucket name.
>
> Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long
>
> Bucket name must be a series of one or more labels separated by a
>   period (.), where each label:
>
> Must start with a lowercase letter or a number
>
> Must end with a lowercase letter or a number
>
> Can contain lowercase letters, numbers and dashes
>
> Bucket names must not be formatted as an IP address (e.g.,
>   192.168.5.4)
>
> The following are examples of valid bucket names:
>
> myawsbucket
>
> my.aws.bucket
>
> myawsbucket.1
>
> The following are examples of invalid bucket names:
>
> Invalid Bucket Name   Comment .myawsbucket    Bucket name cannot start with
>   a period (.). myawsbucket.    Bucket name cannot end with a period (.).
>   my..examplebucket There can only be one period between labels

Note if you want to access a bucket using a virtual hosted-style request, for example http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com over SSL, the bucket name cannot include a period (.).

further reference is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

Comment: This is not correct. The bucket name `myproject.de` is a valid bucket name.

In some instances bucket names must contain periods.(from Amazon Docs http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html): 'In this step, you will sign in to the Amazon S3 console with your AWS account credentials and create the following two buckets: example.com & www.example.com'