# carrierwave image upload to s3 "hostname does not match certificate error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I first got carrierwave working by following the directions from this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Then I hooked up s3 by following the directions here:

http://railgaadi.wordpress.com/2012/06/03/saving-files-in-amazon-s3-using-carrierwave-and-fog-gem/

My image_uploader.rb file:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "development/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :iphone do
    process :resize_to_limit => [320, 160]
  end
end
```

And my fog.rb file:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'AWS',       # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx',       # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'xxx',       # required
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'goodlife.carrierwave'                     # required

end
```

This is the error I'm getting:

hostname "goodlife.carrierwave.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is goodlife.carrierwave the name of your bucket?

Edit:

Remove the period from your bucket name. That should fix it.

From Amazon:

> If you want to access a bucket by using a virtual hosted-style
>   request, for example, http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com over SSL, the
>   bucket name cannot include a period (.).

Comment: yeah that is the name

Answer (score 8):

Adding :path_style => true to config.fog_credentials worked for me. I learned it from an answer to
[Amazon S3 - hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) + rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340551/amazon-s3-hostname-does-not-match-the-server-certificate-opensslsslsslerr).