# After asset:precompile, OpenSSL failure pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, openssl, certificate

Whenever I try to push to Heroku (staging or production), I get an OpenSSL error after asset:precompile that causes the whole push to fail.

```
rake aborted!
   hostname "staging.my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com" does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)
```

I get the same error on my laptop and desktop computers and am not sure what I should do. Where are server certificates stored? Do I need to update or replace them? If yes, where and how?

I'm on Win64, and already looked at [Amazon S3 - hostname does not match the server certificate (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) + rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340551/amazon-s3-hostname-does-not-match-the-server-certificate-opensslsslsslerranswer) , but it's been working for the last 5 months (so bucket naming shouldn't be the issue).

However, I tried changing the access keys/codes a few days ago, but then changed them back. I would expect a different error if they were the cause.

Help appreciated greatly.

Comment: Note to self: https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550 describes how to set up certificates

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203685/2942

Amazon has a certificate for `*.s3.amazonaws.com`, but that doesn't match `staging.my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` (it does match `my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com`).

Just use `s3.amazonaws.com/my-bucket-name/path/to/file` instead.

Comment: Thanks friism, you are right. I already started creating new buckets, but now run into a problem that my system doesn't seem to have the right certificates installed. This might also explain why it worked in the past (2 weeks ago there was no problem at all).

Comment: @MichaelSchmitz It should not be a requirement for your system to have have certs installed.