# SSL Root Certificate Name vs OAuth

Tags: ssl, oauth, ssl-certificate

Currently have a multisite SSL certificate with root certificate name of b.mysite.com and used in both sites of a.mysite.com and b.mysite.com

When third party application trying to communicate with both sites using oauth, the b.mysite.com works but not a.mysite.com

Could this be an error in naming the root certificate name? or something else?

Note: Before implement SSL, oauth works on both sites.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but if you have a certificate for b, it makes sense you can't use it for a, otherwise it would defeat the purpose of certificates, right?

Comment: if i were to have the multisite SSL using root certificate of mysite.com only (without sub-domain a or b), was the right way?

Comment: No, you need a wildcard certificate. This is probably more expensive, but you need it if you want to support any subdomain. Note, if you have sub-subdomains, you need to add another level. See also [wildcard SSL on sub sub domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain) and [What certificates are needed for multi-level subdomain](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/10538/what-certificates-are-needed-for-multi-level-subdomains).

Comment: thanks for the answer.