# x509: certificate is valid for *.xyz.net, not docker.abc.xyz.net

Tags: docker

I am trying to login to a company's private docker repository. When I try to login with:

```
docker login docker.abc.xyz.net
```

it returns only this error:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://docker.abc.xyz.net/v1/users/: x509:  certificate is valid for *.xyz.net, xyg.net, not docker.abc.xyz.net
```

We have a `ca.cert`, which I have put at the following location:

```
/Users/myName/etc/docker/certs.d/docker.abc.xyz.net/ca.cert
```

I also tried putting it here:

```
/private/etc/docker/certs.d/docker.abc.xyz.net/ca.cert
```

and finally used this command to try to get keychain access for the cert:

```
sudo security add-trusted-cert -d -r trustRoot -k /Library/Keychains/System.keychain ca.crt
```

I even gave full access to the cert to see if that would be picked up. I have tried restarting docker as well, but nothing is accepting my certificate. Does anyone else have any ideas what might be preventing the login attempt on Docker Mac?

```
--------------
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            6c:ac:dd:00:bf:96:38:c3
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: CN=ON DWCC Unclass Testing CA-1
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun  6 19:40:49 2016 GMT
            Not After : Jun  6 19:40:49 2018 GMT
        Subject: C=US, O=Navy, OU=ONI, CN=docker.abc.xyz.net
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus (2048 bit):

                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 

            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:

            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:docker.abc.xyz.net
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. I've tried to fix things up here enough to make the question readable, but ideally questions should at least meet that bar when first asked.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip Charles

Comment: Please check your DNS. for linux: vi /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 11):

This is actually correct, standards-compliant behavior. A `*.xyz.net` wildcard certificate is valid for `abc.xyz.net` or `docker.xyz.net`, but not `docker.abc.xyz.net`.

Quoting the answer to [a question directly focused on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain), in turn quoting [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
> [RFC2459](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2459).  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
> the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
> of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
> character `*` which is considered to match any single domain name
> component or component fragment. E.g., `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but
> not `bar.foo.a.com`. `f*.com` matches `foo.com` but not `bar.com`.

---

Consider adding an appropriate SubjectAltName to your certificate, if you can't regenerate it altogether.

Comment: I know the matcher is only on the front part of that, and i am discussing that with our tech. But others have been able to get this cert to work, but me on my mac can't. I tried http://container-solutions.com/adding-self-signed-registry-certs-docker-mac/ but it still isn't working. Was coming on here to see if there may be something mac related to docker.

Comment: Different SSL client libraries have different levels of compliance with the relevant RFCs -- some of them allow wildcards to recurse, but *those that do are buggy*. Docker, and the SSL library it's using on your Mac, are doing the Right Thing here, and whichever platform/software accepts that certificate for a 2nd-level wildcard is buggy.

Comment: Anyhow, if you're having a different problem with a different certificate, that would be... well... a *different problem*, deserving its own question if not already answered somewhere else.

Comment: our tech said the certificate was set specifically for https://docker.abc.xyz.net/ so I am not sure why it thinks I am looking for *.xyz.net/?

Comment: @tcoulson, the error message makes it very clear what the issue at hand is. I couldn't accept what your tech is claiming to you as true without being shown supporting evidence (for example, output from `openssl x509 -in yourcert.crt -noout -text`).

Comment: I added in the text you asked for.

Comment: The certificate you gave doesn't match up with the error message -- the error message is specific to wildcard certs, and the certificate given isn't a wildcard cert at all. I'd suggest investigating whether the cert actually being used is the one you think it is, *or* if the error message is still an exact match for the one given in your question.