# Wildcard for second level subdomain

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain, aws-certificate-manager

[image]

AWS Certificate manager isn't allowing me to add a 2 level wildcard domain name, which would match `x.a.example.com`, `y.b.example.com` etc.

Is there a workaround for this? (instead of creating `*.a.example.com`, `*.b.example.com` etc)

Comment: No, there is no other way. In x.509 certificates, wildcard can cover only single subdomain level and can be only the leftmost character.

Comment: You can use SAN and add each subdomain to the same cert.  A bit of a pain, but better than multiple certs.

Comment: Note for people arriving here: Google Chrome caches SSL certificates. So if you changed your certificate from `*.example.` to `*.a.example.com` and Chrome still says your certificate is invalid, it's probably still the old one (you can click on the padlock on the left of the URL and check what certificate Chrome sees for your site). If it's still the old one, you can refresh the cache a few times.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html

> **Wildcard Names** ACM allows you to use an asterisk (*) in the domain name to create an ACM Certificate containing a wildcard name that can
> protect several sites in the same domain. For example, *.example.com
> protects [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and images.example.com.
>
> Note: When you request a wildcard certificate, the asterisk (*) must
> be in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only
> one subdomain level. For example, *.example.com can protect
> login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect
> test.login.example.com. Also note that *.example.com protects only the
> subdomains of example.com, it does not protect the bare or apex domain
> (example.com). However, you can request a certificate that protects a
> bare or apex domain and its subdomains by specifying multiple domain
> names in your request. For example, you can request a certificate that
> protects example.com and *.example.com.

Unfortunately this is not possible/supported.

Comment: Okay. But what about multiple subdomains and only one wildcard? like "*.preview.site.com"

Answer (score 2):

For those who are having issues for multiple sub domain in their certificate.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/associate-ssl-certificates-cloudfront/

You can't associate more than one SSL or Transport Layer Security (TLS) certificate to an individual CloudFront distribution. However, certificates provided by [AWS Certificate Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-overview.html) (ACM) support [up to 10 subject alternative names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-limits.html), including wildcards. To enable SSL or HTTPS for multiple domains served through one CloudFront distribution, assign a certificate from ACM that includes all the required domains.

To use your own SSL certificate for multiple domain names with CloudFront, import your certificate into ACM or the AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) certificate store. For instructions, see [Importing an SSL/TLS Certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cnames-and-https-procedures.html#cnames-and-https-uploading-certificates).

Answer (score 1):

You can have **Subject Alternative Name**s or SANs in the certificate for named domains: https://geekflare.com/san-ssl-certificate/

Certificate Signing Request or CSR generation would be something like this:

```
openssl req -new -key my.key -out my.csr -subj "/CN=*.domain.com" -addext "subjectAltName=DNS:one.complex.domain.com,DNS:completely.another.domain.com"
```

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127802/339052

Comment: Great link, but just FYI to users the `san.cnf` file is required too.