# Is it possible to have wildcard with SAN entries with `*` in 2nd label in single SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, dns, ssl-certificate, hosting

please help to find the answer to 3 questions. 
1. Is it possible to buy one single certificate for domain `mydomain.com` which would work as the wildcard for `*.mydomain.com` and has SAN record for `label1.*.mydomain.com` and `label2.*.mydomain.com`?
2. How much it would be costs to add one more SAN record like `label3.*.mydomain.com`?
3. How long it takes to add one more SAN record like `label3.*.mydomain.com`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not allowed. Asterist character can be presented only once as a leftmost character and followed by a dot. No other wildcards are allowed in `DNSName` name type.

Valid names:

```
*.domain.com
*.sub.domain.com
*.sub1.sub2.domain.com
```

Invalid names:

```
*char.domain.com
*.*.domain.com
char*char.domain.com
char*.domain.com
sub.*.domain.com
<...>
```

More information with reference links on [Wildcard Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)

Comment: Can you provide please any ref to the spec or something?

Comment: added ref in edits

Comment: You could have Subject Alternative Name components in the cert: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117202/339052, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127802/339052