# mod_rewrite rule htaccess not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i want https://www.kita-neukoelln.tandembtl.de/ go to https://kita-neukoelln.tandembtl.de/

it is only working with chrome and IE11, is there a way for other browser?
they check ssl for www.subdomain.domain.de before redirect :(

Thanks

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.kita-neukoelln.tandembtl\.de$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) https://kita-neukoelln.tandembtl.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I get a certificate error in every browser I've tried.

The problem, `www.kita-neukoelln.tandembtl.de` is a sub-subdomain and the security certificate for `*.tandembtl.de` [does not cover it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain):

> A wildcard SSL certificate for *.example.net will match
>   sub.example.net but not sub.sub.example.net.