# Subdomain on CloudFront not working (certificate not accepted)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

- In the Cert Manager I have a valid certificate, which includes the *.example.com domain.
- In CloudFront I have a distribution with HTTP to HTTPS redirect enabled and empty CNAME field.
- When I edit the distribution and enter staging.example.com in the CNAME field and select the certificate I get the following error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.cloudfront.model.InvalidViewerCertificateException: The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add. For more details, see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html#alternate-domain-names-requirements (Service: AmazonCloudFront; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidViewerCertificate; Request ID: 8406d8d5-65c3-11e9-afc0-65457a0a2bea)
```

Am I missing something? The other distribution for the top level domain is working fine with the same certificate.

Comment: I faced an exact same issue once; I had simply made a mistake when generating the certificate and forgot to include the alternative/wildcard SAN. The error also indicates this; the certificate is a valid certificate, but it doesn't cover staging.example.com and thus fails.

Comment: Add the certificate to the distribution, then save changes, then add the subdomain as alternate domain name, and then save changes again.  Any difference?

Comment: As per the error message, the certificate that you have does not cover the alternative domain name. So, please make sure that you have a certificate with a wildcard to cover multiple subdomains. Cause standard certificate only covers www.example.com subdomain.

Comment: In my case, I could add www.example.com.. it worked. but when I tried to also add example.com as an Alternative Domain in the CloudFront distrubution then it triggers the error, the certificate is registered with the wildcard properly.

Comment: I have the ACM added for the wildcard domain *.abc.com and its not accepting the root domain abc.com but accepts www.abc.com weird

Answer (score 25):

Make sure that you are only trying to get the `*.` to match a single subdomain. See [wildcard ssl on sub-subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115611/wildcard-ssl-on-sub-subdomain)

That is to say that `*.example.com` will match `sub1.example.com` and `sub2.example.com`, but it will not match `sub2.sub1.example.com`. Finally, you **CANNOT** request a certificate for `*.*.example.com`. In order to match that last case you would have to request `*.sub1.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already have the correct wildcard thing in my certificate, see the first point in my question. Found the problem and answered my question below.

Answer (score 13):

Figured it out.

The certificate was generated on the wrong region. **Certificates that will be used on a CloudFront distribution must be generated on us-east-1 (Virginia).**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I created an SSL in **us-east-1 (North Virginia)** but I was still facing the issue and when I checked that SSL in the ACM, it was only for subdomains I forgot to add a root domain while requesting the SSL.

So whenever you want to use an ACM make sure that the SSL certificate is for the domain and subdomains (if required).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using serverless, try adding `certificateArn` as component inputs in the `serverless.yml` file

```
your-app:
  component: "@sls-next/serverless-component@latest"
  inputs:
    domain: ["app", "domain.com"] # [ sub-domain, domain ]
    certificateArn: "arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:<id>"
```

Reference : https://github.com/serverless-nextjs/serverless-next.js/issues/821