# Wildcard SSL - HTTPS redirection www certificate error

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, wildcard, no-www

I purchased a wildcard for the following domain = `*.example.com`

My website URL is = `https://sub.example.com`

I configured redirections through apache2 VirtualHosts like this (to force "http" to "https", and "www" to "no-www") =

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.example.com
        ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

        # Redirect 301 to HTTPS
        Redirect permanent / https://sub.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName sub.example.com
        ServerAlias www.sub.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # Redirect www to no-www
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

        # TLS
        SSLEngine               On
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/apache2/ssl/wildcard.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/digicert.pem
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
</VirtualHost>
```

Redirects are working fine for http (80) requests =

- `http://sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com` ==> **WORKS**
- `http://www.sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com` ==> **WORKS**

But not for https (443) requests with "www" =

- `https://www.sub.example.com` to `https://sub.example.com` ==> **ERROR**

The browser returns the following error = *NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*

During my researches, I found that some people get the same problem and the provided solution is to take a wildcard to cover the "www" part.

This is my case, I have a wildcard.

Could someone tell me why I got this error ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it seems impossible to make it work with a wildcard. I found my answer on another topic, here = https://stackoverflow.com/a/9743652/5903520